# Qt5 кросс-компиляция (прикладная: windows7 / целевая ubuntu)

Tags: qt5, кросс-компиляция

По порядку: моя машина под Windows 7

1. установил opensource Qt5.13.2 (не компилировал, просто скачал с офф.сайта готовый установщик)
2. написал приложение в IDE QtCreator
3. скомпилировал с помощью MinGW32 который шел вместе с Qt;

Вопрос: как(что) настроить в QtCreator-е и(или) проекте и затем скомпилировать под Linux системы? Проверять буду на виртуальной машине c Ubuntu 18.

Ответ требуется именно по кросс-компиляции!

Comment: Лучше компилировать сразу на нужной ОС.Попробуй `docker`

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Вам поможет [эта статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/258951/). Нужно импортировать `MXE` в `Qt` Вообще `MXE` пользуются, в основном из-под Linux но говорят он прекрасно импортируется в QtCreator.

Вот инструкция по установке на Linux

> 1. Скачать командой `git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git`
> 2. установить зависимости сборки (гайд [тут](https://mxe.cc/#requirements))
> 3. Скомпилировать под Windows командой `cd mxe && make qtbase`
>
> Сначала будут построены зависимости и инструменты кросс-сборки; Это
>   займет менее часа на быстрой машине с приличным доступом в интернет.
>
> Из-за новой модульной природы Qt 5 различные основные компоненты Qt
>   теперь находятся в разных архивах. Команда, `qtbase`должна дать
>   вам достаточно функциональности для запуска обычных приложений с
>   графическим интерфейсом.
>
> Если вы хотите собрать весь Qt 5, вам нужно запустить `make
>   qt5`(вместо `make qtbase`). Обратите внимание, что это займет намного
>   больше времени, поэтому убедитесь, что вам нужны дополнительные
>   функции.
>
> Перейдите в каталог вашего приложения и запустите инструмент
>   генератора Qt Makefile:
>
> ```
> <mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5
> ```
>
> Создайте свой проект:
>
> ```
> make
> ```
>
> Вы должны найти двоичный файл в каталоге ./release:
>
> ```
> wine release/foo.exe
> ```
>
> В результате получается 32-битный статический исполняемый файл,
>   который будет хорошо работать в 64-битной Windows.
>
> Если вы хотите 64-битный исполняемый файл, соберите Qt с:
>
> ```
> make MXE_TARGETS=x86_64-w64-mingw32.static qtbase
> ```

Инструкция [в оригинале](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows)

Из-под Windows Можно попробовать воспользоваться [CygWin](https://cygwin.com/install.html). Вот [статья](https://www.a2p.it/wordpress/tech-stuff/development/remote-debugging-raspberrypi/) по настройке. Но с ним я не работал.

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что необходимо самому перекомпилировать Qt5 из исходников вместе с mxe?

Comment: @GoodSimon Да, нужно настроить Qt и перекомпилировать Ваша проект  Инструкции по установке зависимостей есть в статье и пункте 2 инструкции.

Comment: @GoodSimon переустанавливать Qt или QtCreator не нужно (если он стоит у Вас на Linux) просто добавьте зависимости, как показано в инструкции и настройте компилятор как в пункте 5 статьи.

Comment: А на Windows7? Мне не удобно работать под Linux системами, по этому и ищу путь как выполнить кросс-компиляцию из под Windows7

Comment: @GoodSimon  У Вас же целевая система Linux (Так написано в заголовке вопроса) Тут уже придется пожертвовать удобством. На Windows нет кросс-компилятора насколько я знаю

Comment: @GoodSimon Хотя я забыл про Cygwin)) Но с ним не работал.

Comment: @GoodSimon Все ссылки добавил в ответ

Comment: Целевая означает: "на чём будет" запускаться скомпилированная программа, а прикладная та в которой ведётся разработка.

Comment: QtCreator на win7, а скомпилировать надо, чтобы запустилось на Linux-е

Comment: Вот и требуется подробная инструкция